# Como Registar Dominio NIC Chile en Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, web, dns, dominio, hosting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo añadir un registro TXT a mi proveedor de DNS ya que NIC CHILE no da la opcion de añadir un registro TXT. ¿como lo hago?, Ellos me respondieron que lo tenia que hacer a través de una empresa de hosting, que esas empresas daban esos servicios. entonces quede en jaque.¿que puedo hacer? Como dije antes esta pregunta ya fue hecha a nic chile, y la respuesta es nos se puede pero ¿los que usan Firebase Hosting Como lo hacen para relacionar con el dominio?

Gracias!!

Comment: que opcion es la que NO da nic.cl?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta consulta debe hacerse a NIC Chile

Comment: ahi puse que opcion No da nic.cl

Comment: nic.cl no es un proveedor de DNS, ellos solo registran el dominio. Tienes que crear un DNS en un proveedor (https://freedns.afraid.org/ es gratuito) y apuntar el dominio a ESE DNS.